# CombinedGeometry/Geometry.Combine() equivalent in Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight

Geometry class in WPF contains a [Combine() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms607449.aspx) which is extremely useful when you need to exclude one geometry from the other, etc. Silverlight version of Geometry doesn't have such a method. The same goes for [CombinedGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.combinedgeometry.aspx) class which does the same.

Are there any other options to exclude one geometry from another in Silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a WPF app which builds user-defined masks using Combine. If there's no answer in SL 4 (none I can see) then my fallback is to send the raw geometry back to the server for combination

Answer (score 0):

I may be very late to answer this question ;-) there is an option called [GeometryGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometrygroup%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). You may use this to exclude one geometry from other in Silverlight. You are required to set FillRule="EvenOdd".

Comment: That's not the same thing. The fill rule specifies how the outlines are _to be filled_. In particular, if the geometry path isn't filled (but outlined), it won't matter what fill rule you use. - The `Combine` method used to exclude one geometry from another actually modifies the outlines. This means that the resulting geometry could become smaller than the one subtracted from - something that could never happen with grouping the geometry with others.